# R plot: creating a plot per category from imported .csv data

Tags: r

I have been given a .csv data set that contains a list of events by date. Each event occurs in an area, has a method, and can have one of two results.

Multiple events can occur on any given day.

My task is to produce the following:

1) produce a plot of result1, result2, resulttotal per day.
2) produce a plot of result1, result2, resulttotal per method.
3) produce a plot of result1, result2, resulttotal per area.

There are other tools I can use to accomplish these, but I would like to take this opportunity to see how well R works for me.

I can also accomplish the task my turning the dataset into multiple datasets - I want to avoid this.

I can probably accomplish the task by using nested loops - I'm hoping to avoid this.

I have tried variations on the code below, but the main problem I am experiencing is (for each task)

1) getting totals per day
2) getting totals per method
3) getting totals per area

I have discovered how to treat each line of data discretely, but not how to run totals. In other words, I can produce a bar plot or line plot where every datum is shown, but not totals per category (date, method, or area).

I hope I am making sense!

So my question in short is: can someone please point me in the right direction? If I determine how to make one of the three plots, I am sure I can extrapolate to the other two. I don't think I need complete code, just a push in the right direction.

```
#1
mydata <- read.csv("c:\\users\\jim\\downloads\\book1.csv", header=FALSE)
counts <- table(mydata$V5, mydata$V1)
barplot(counts, xlab="Date", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(counts))

#2
mydata <- read.csv("c:\\users\\jim\\downloads\\book1.csv", header=FALSE)
mydata$V3 <- as.numeric(mydata$V3) 
mydata$V4 <- as.numeric(mydata$V4) 
mydata$V5 <- as.numeric(mydata$V5) 
plot(mydata$V1, mydata$V5,
      xlab = "Day", 
      ylab = "Events",
      main = "November Events",
      type = "l",
      col = "red",
     lwd=3)

Date        Method  Result1 Result2 ResultTotal Location
2015/11/01  Method1 0       3       3           Area1
2015/11/01  Method2 12      0       12          Area2
2015/11/03  Method3 0       3       3           Area1
2015/11/03  Method3 0       1       1           Area1
2015/11/04  Method1 1       0       1           Area1
2015/11/04  Method4 3       10      13          Area3
2015/11/05  Method4 5       0       5           Area4
2015/11/06  Method5 0       2       2           Area1
2015/11/06  Method3 0       1       1           Area1
2015/11/06  Method5 0       1       1           Area1
2015/11/07  Method2 12      15      27          Area5
2015/11/09  Method1 0       4       4           Area1
2015/11/09  Method3 0       1       1           Area1
2015/11/09  Method3 0       1       1           Area1
2015/11/09  Method4 3       14      17          Area6
2015/11/09  Method4 4       20      24          Area7
2015/11/12  Method4 43      240     283         Area8
2015/11/13  Method5 2       2       4           Area1
2015/11/13  Method6 19      33      52          Area5
2015/11/13  Method2 129     352     481         Area9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to aggregate data is the `data.table`-way. In your case you would aggregate the data as follows, furthermore, the plotting is done using `ggplot2`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mydata) # convert to a data.table

# aggregate data
dt[, byArea := .N, by = Location] # assuming that you want to get the number of locations...
dt[, byDate := .N, by = Date]
dt[, byMethod := .N, by = Method]

# say you want to have a barplot:
library(ggplot2)

P <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = Method, y = byMethod)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
P
```

Is that what you where looking for?

Comment: This looks very promising thanks. I get errors such as "Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L,  : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors" but I am sure I can figure these out.

Comment: Solved the problems - thanks again. You have taught me useful things beyond the scope of the question I asked.